# xlwings pywin error (-2147023170) 'the remote procedure call failed.' and killing the app

Tags: excel, xlwings

I am running a code to create graphs on excel as chartsheets (lets say 100) with 4 to 10 series on each.

The line is this:

```
        chart = data_sheet.charts.add()
```

Which yields:
`ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(181, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((5, 1), (5, 1), (5, 1), (5, 1)),Left pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'Échec de l’appel de procédure distante.', None, None)`

and kills excel closing the app and the open files. Where the line had worked fine before

Been trying to fix it, tried just bypassing the creation but then at the next call of any other .api i get:

`self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args), pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023174, 'Le serveur RPC n’est pas disponible.', None, None)`

Does anyone knows how to prevent this from happening? I'm thinking the file created on which I'm working is damaged but I can't know for sure. Does it have something to do with my pc servers?

Comment: Solved it. This sort of errors are not evident. The sheet in which i was creating the graphs was too "heavy" and made it crash. Solved it by creating the graphs in a different sheet.